# Working vs an old project and find code which I don't understand

Tags: javascript

I don't understand following code please explain it to me
 I am sorry it might seem  weird, but I gotta understand it

```
reverse = [-1, 1][+!!reverse];
```

Comment: Wave the wand and say "SHow me more code"

Comment: This appears to be taking an variable called reverse, and if it's true-y it makes it the number 1, if it's false-y it makes it -1. If you could provide more context for that line I'm sure someone could give a more accurate answer as to why.

Comment: ok, but what about +. I understand !! does nothing, couse it ignores two times right?

Comment: + converts it from a true|false value to a 0 or 1. and !! doesn't do nothing, the first `!` checks whether it is falsey or not, and then the second `!` flips answer. It just appears to do nothing if you only have true/false values for reverse. But you can see it does have an effect if you use non true/false values for reverse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say `reverse = 5`, then `!5` is `false` since every number except 0 is thruty, now if we negate again `!false` we obtain `true` and we finally convert our boolean expression to either 1 or 0 using `+`.

```
var reverse = 5;
reverse = [-1, 1][+!!reverse];
```

is the same as

```
var reverse = 5;
reverse = [-1, 1][1];
```

To be more explicit it could have been:

```
var reverse = 5;
reverse = [-1, 1][Number(Boolean(reverse))];
```

Answer (score 2):

`!!reverse` converts the variables to a boolean

`+!!reverse'` converts it to a number (0 or 1)

that number is used as the index for the array on the left part

so the whole statement will set `reverse` to -1 if original value was falsy or 1 if original value was truthy

A simpler way to right the above statement is

`reverse = reverse? 1:-1;`

Answer (score 2):

Okay, this was written by someone who tought themselves quite clever, but forgot that great code is not just fast, but also easy to read.

The first part

```
[-1,1]
```

contructs an array with -1 at index 0 and 1 at index 1.

```
!!reverse
```

Will convert reverse into a true boolean value.

The unary version of the + operator (Unary operator are operators that only take one argument) will convert the boolean version of reverse into a number.

This means that if reverse is truthy, reverse will be changed to 1, while if it is falsy, it will be changed to -1.